# Prove that there exists an $x' \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x') = \frac{\int^b_a fg}{\int^b_a g}$ for the given conditions.

Tags: real-analysis

Say that $f$ and $g$ are two continuous real-valued functions on an interval $[a, b]$ whose values are all strictly positive.

Say that $m[f;[a, b]] \int^b_a g ≤\int^b_a fg ≤ M[f;[a, b]] \int^b_a g$ in this case.

Given $m[f;I]$ is $inf\{f(x): x \in I\}$ and $M[f:I]$ is $sup\{f(x): x\in I\}$ where I is the interval $[a,b]$

I'm trying to prove that there exists an $x' \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x') = \frac{\int^b_a fg}{\int^b_a g}$.

I know that the fraction of integrals is less than or equal to the supremum and greater than or equal to the infimum of the function $f$ on this interval. That's given. If the fraction is equal to either of them, then we're done. If it's not, it must still be on the range of values bounded by those two points. Hence there will be some value in that range that is equal to the fraction.

Is there a better way of stating this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hint:

Define $$I(x)=\int_{a}^xf(t)g(t)dt-\int_{a}^b f(t)g(t)dt
\frac{\int_{a}^xg(t)dt}{\int_{a}^bg(t)dt}$$

Note that $I(a)=I(b)=0$. By Rolle's theorem there exists $\xi\in (a,b)$ such that $I'(\xi)=0$. Can you finish from here?